# How to use response of a .findAll()?

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js, sequelize.js

I am working on a bot discord in Javascript and i have to deal with a database. I'm able to create/update/destroy data. But there is still one only thing that i can't do.
I try to do a `.findAll()` with a `where: {}` to select some data. But i don't know how to access to the response and how to deal with it ? I need this to compare every team to create a kind of matchmaking.

There is my code and what i get from the database :

```
static async isTeamReady(sequelize, teamModel, bot) {
    await teamModel.findAll({
        where: {
            lookingForAWar: true
        },
        raw: true
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        message.author.send("Something went wrong")            
    })
}
```

```
[
  {
    id: 7,
    teamName: 'LastStrike2',
    clanTagInGame: '#2YQPUR2RY',
    leaderTag: 'Crayzze',
    secretKey: 'VYWJ01FW',
    lookingForAWar: 1,
    elo: 0,
    win: 0,
    loose: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-03-22T12:26:49.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-03-22T15:25:36.000Z
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    teamName: 'Test',
    clanTagInGame: '#2YQPUR2RY',
    leaderTag: '<@!224209300774584320>',
    secretKey: '0I1J2OR0',
    lookingForAWar: 1,
    elo: 0,
    win: 0,
    loose: 0,
    createdAt: 2021-03-22T15:26:39.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-03-22T15:26:55.000Z
  }
]
```

Thx for your help !
And have a good day ;)

Crayzze

**EDIT:**

Ok, well I just found it.
I put a `var res =` just before the `await teamModel`
I removed the `.then ()`

In this way I was able to recover each field by simply making a loop:

```
static async isTeamReady(sequelize, teamModel, bot) {
    const res = await teamModel.findAll({
        where: {
            lookingForAWar: true
        },
        raw: true
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        message.author.send("Something went wrong")           
    })
 
    var i = 0
    while (i < res.length) {
        console.log(res[i].teamName)
        i++
    }
}
```

I put it down if it can help a next one ;)

Comment: Put `const response = ` before `await teamModel.findAll(...)` to store it.

Comment: @ChrisG when i'm oing it, I have an ```undifined``` :/

Comment: And i don't know how to access to this data, because when i try with ```.toJSON()```, i have something like this ```TypeError: response.toJSON is not a function```

Comment: I found a solution, i edit my post !
Thx for your help ;)